# How to split a line and assign variables in Bash

Tags: bash, wget

How do you:

- read from a text file
- split each line with a comma
- and assign it to variables in bash?

**filelist**

renamedfile.xml,url-01.php 
renamedFileDifferent.xml,url-02.php 
specificFileRename.xml,"url-03"
newFilename.xml,"url-04"

I'm looking to accomplish something like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash 
    while read line 
      do   
          wget -c -O newfile remoteFile >/dev/null 2>&1  
    done < filelist
```

Also, what is a typical place to place shell files for cron jobs?

Comment: Looks like you are splitting on comma and a space, not just a comma.

Comment: As far as your side question, it is just a preference. I use $HOME/bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the special IFS variable (internal field seperator), you can cause bash to split on  commas instead of the default tab, newline, and space.

```
while IFS=',' read -r newfile remotefile; do
    wget -q -c -O "$newfile" "http://somesite/$remotefile"
done < filelist
```

The quotes in your sample file will have a problem with this. You can use a parameter expansion to strip the quotes.

```
while IFS=',' read -r newfile remotefile; do
    wget -q -c -O "$newfile" "http://somesite/${remotefile//\"/}"
done < filelist
```

If the quotes are actually intended to be part of the filename, then it will need to be url encoded. You can use a parameter expansion for this as well.

```
while IFS=',' read -r newfile remotefile; do
    wget -q -c -O "$newfile" "http://somesite/${remotefile//\"/%22}"
done < filelist
```